# Why must the $B_\theta$ and $B_\phi$ components of the magnetic field be zero at $\theta=0\, \&\, \pi$?

Tags: calculus, vector-fields, electromagnetism

I have been reading [this paper](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1990ApJ...352..343L) and it says (see the last paragraph in the screenshot below) that 'the latter condition requires that $B_\theta$ and $B_\phi$ vanish along the axis $\mu=1,\ -1$'. Why does $B_\theta$ and $B_\phi$ need to be zero at $\theta=0,\ \pi$?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason $B_\theta$ and $B_\phi$ must be zero at $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$ is that the value of $\phi$ is ambiguous at these coordinates. Since the unit vectors are given by
$$\mathbf{\hat{\theta}} = \cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)\mathbf{\hat{x}} + \cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)\mathbf{\hat{y}} - \sin(\theta)\mathbf{\hat{z}}$$
$$\mathbf{\hat{\phi}}=-\sin(\phi)\mathbf{\hat{x}} + \cos(\phi)\mathbf{\hat{y}},$$
if $B_\theta$ or $B_\phi$ are non-zero at $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$ then the direction the vector points in is ambiguous. Hence, setting $B_\theta=B_\phi=0$ at $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$ removes this ambiguity.